# Ios label enables with some time delay

Tags: ios

I am keeping two labels hidden while loading. when i pressed a button it will enabled by taking 5 secs time delay in ios. Any suggestions and sample coding regarding this.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide the labels like this

```
label.hidden = TRUE;
```

and in `btn` action write this code.

```
- (IBAction)btnPressed
{
 [self performSelector:@selector(showLabel) afterDelay:5];
}

- (void)showLabel
{
label.hidden = FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
       target:self
       selector:@selector(showLabels:)
       userInfo:nil
       repeats:NO];
}

- (void)showLabels:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    self.myLabel1.hidden = NO;
    self.myLabel2.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot friend!!! I done with this. It works well.